# Is there any way to find out which GPIO pin of raspberry pi busy?

Tags: gpio, pi-2

We will get many times `"Device or resource busy"` error, when try to read or write GPIO pin of raspberry pi.

So, **Is there any way to find out which GPIO pin of raspberry pi busy?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you get that error, the GPIO should be busy. That's one way to find out. Do you need a different way? If yes, why?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest looking for entries in `/sys/class/gpio`.  If GPIO X is in use by the kernel there will be a gpioX directory.

Comment: This isn't true.  If a GPIO pin is used by the *kernel*, it won't show up in `/sys/class/gpio`; pins only show up here if they are being used by a user-space process using the sysfs filesystem interface.  Anything that interacts with the gpio pins through a kernel driver (e.g, the `bcm2835_gpiomem` driver, which exposes `/dev/gpiomem`) will not create entries in the sysfs directory.

Comment: @larsks True, however I wouldn't class GPIO access via `/dev/mem` or `/dev/gpiomem` as use by the kernel, all the kernel does is allow access to the register memory.  It has no knowledge of what the user process may be doing and would not raise the "Device or resource busy" error mentioned in the question.